# ObjC: ‘NSLog’ versus ‘printf’ for printing C byte arrays

Tags: objective-c, printf, nslog

When the need arises to print to the console the contents of a C byte array (not ASCII), ‘printf’ has the advantage, when stepping through the array, that it does not put a return after each use. Thus the array is printed concisely across the screen. However, it often takes an age for the printout actually to reach the screen and in desperation, I sometimes open or close ‘Terminal’ as this seems to flush out the printout (‘fflush’ does not).

‘NSLog’, on the other hand, prints quickly but one often sees here and elsewhere that it must be applied with each step through the array. Unfortunately, this inserts a return after each use, causing even a short array to cover the page and making it difficult to read or copy.

For the record, I thought it worth pointing out that there is a simple solution, using ‘NSMutableString’ and ‘appendFormat’, that prints across the page. Here is the ‘bells and whistles’ version with commas, spaces and enclosing braces that I keep handy for testing purposes. It is constructed as a C function and prints in decimal (%d); for other formats see  Apple’s ‘String Programming Guide’ at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html.

```
void byteArrayLog(unsigned char *bArray, int numBytes)
{
    int i;  
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSMutableString* dString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:5*numBytes];//Create a mutable string. Note the length.
    [dString appendString:@"{"];//Start with "{".
    for(i = 0; i < numBytes-1; i++)
        [dString appendFormat:@"%d, ", bArray[i]];//Format a byte, follow with a comma and a space.
    [dString appendFormat:@"%d}", bArray[i]];//Format the final byte, finish with a "}".

    NSLog(@"Array contents = %@", dString);//Print to the console.

    [pool drain];//Clean up.
}
```

Comment: `NSLog()` prints to `stderr`, whereas `printf()` prints to `stdout`. It seems that the standard output is not flushed but the standard error stream is - try using `fprintf(stderr, "format string: %d", array[index]);` in order to print to stderr using a `printf()`-style function.

Comment: asl is apple's syslog, introduced in ios4/osx 10.6 :) man asl_search. it has a nice api for querying old logs

Comment: @Daij-Djan syslog grabs data from standard error.

Comment: ok :) didnt know :) thanks. :) only knew printf didnt show up in asl.. know I now :D

Comment: Good suggestion @H2CO3. At first glance it seems to work. With 'fflush' not working I was deflected from exploring that route. Hopefully, the post will be useful in other contexts as this type of dilemma seems to arise often in posts. For NSBum, forestalling questions is also occasionally useful:-)

Comment: @user1572284 I made this an answer, please upvote & accept if it helped. Thanks.

Comment: Oh oh, I take it back @H2CO3. I have just tried 'fprintf(stderr...' with a 256 byte array and it spreads the result over several lines in arbitrary fashion. Thanks for responding though.

Comment: "and it spreads the result over several lines" - if the console to which you're printing is not wide enough... Also, without knowing what your array contains, I can't help much more.

Comment: I'm sorry @H2CO3, I should have been more specific. With 256 bytes of unsigned char data, the printout has typically three time signatures and PID's – the data are partitioned. This, of course, is vastly better than 256 lines. This whole thing was only a minor irritation in the first place during testing and debugging (I sometimes copy and paste the results into Mathematica for analysis), but it got to me sufficiently for me finally to do something. As my post does work, I'll probably revert to it but again, thanks.

Comment: @user1572284 So is it actually raw binary data?

Comment: @H2CO3. Yes, it's raw data, each byte ranging anywhere from 0 to 255.

Comment: @user1572284 And you're trying to print it using `%c`, amirite?

Comment: @H2CO3. No, %d or %x are my preferences as the data are not ASCII, but I don't think the format matters.

Comment: @user1572284 Alright. I thought it was the problem, but apparently it isn't.

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for? I usually print this kind of stuff with an `NSData`, which will `NSLog` just fine with `%@`.

Answer (score 1):

`NSLog()` prints to the standard error stream (`stderr`), whereas `printf()` prints to the standard output (`stdout`). It seems that the standard output is not flushed properly but the standard error stream is - try using

```
fprintf(stderr, "format string: %d", array[index]);
```

in order to print to `stderr` using a `printf()`-style function.

Comment: This works nicely as one steps through short arrays (~10 bytes) but for longer ones (~100 bytes and more) it partitions the data; however, nowhere near as much as 'NSLog'.